# QGIS HTML labels only for objects visible on map

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm printing QR-code that is generated on the fly in QGIS Print Composer. The URL to get the QR-code ist stored in a PostgreSQL database in the attribute-field "url".

```html
<img src = "[% "url" %]"  
    style="width: auto; height: 100%; display: block; margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;" />
```

In Print Composer this works fine as long as the map, I use is part of an Atlas. When the map switches to another Atlas-feature, the generated QR-code is updated.

My problem is, that I want to use a map without the Atlas functionality.
How can I get the URL only for the feature (supposing that only one feature is displayed) that is displayed on the map in Print Composer?

I was looking trough the expressions from QGIS, but did not find a suitable function to catch the data of a feature on a defined layer within the extent of a a map in Print Composer.

Comment: you can try something like: attributes(get_feature('layername_or_layerid','field_to_identify','value_to_identify'))['atttributename']

Answer (score 1):

### Etape 1

Define an **item id** in the item properties of your map (example : map1)

In the scope of the layout you have now access to the properties of the item map1 with the function the expression

`item_variables('map1')`

You could have the extent of the *map1* with :

`map_get(item_variables('map1'),'map_extent')`

### Etape 2

Add your label with the expression :

```
with_variable('map_extent', 
    map_get(item_variables('map1'), 'map_extent'),
     array_first(
        aggregate(
            'LAYERNAME_OR_LAYERID', 
            'array_agg', 
            "FIELDNAME", 
            filter:=intersects($geometry, @map_extent)
        )
    )
)
```

It uses the `with_variable` function to create the *map_extent* variable (`@map_extent`) to make the expression more readable.

#### NB

You may have some bug with the message "No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression.". If you can note validate the expression, just copy/paste your expression with the `[% ... %]` **outside the expression builder**.